# Is there a way to make a remote softlink in machine A redirect to 'filename' machine B

Tags: linux, symlink

I want write some log in machine B after some operations. However, I have more than mone server, and some operations are in another machine. Now I send message to machine A, then machine A write log to log-file. Is there an easier way to do it? I know in the same machine softlink is useful, but in different machine does it work and if YES, how?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Because a symlinks needs to be in the same file system. (a little bit of generalization here, this is valid for local fs like ext)

- You can have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/291423/how-to-copy-a-file-without-using-scp-inside-an-ssh-session
  to see how to copy files through ssh.
- Or use pipes over ssh https://www.maketecheasier.com/ssh-pipes-linux/
- There are also ways to remote attach to syslog daemon, but I do not recommend to do this through unprotected network (like www). e.g. https://www.linux.com/learn/remote-logging-syslog-part-1-basics. This may also require some port forwarding stuff...
- You could also add some network mount with samba/cifs

but most of this is a lot of configuration for just some lines of logging.